# Expected value of given random variables

Tags: random-variables, expected-value

A fair dice is rolled 3 times. Let X denote the sum of the dice rolls, and Y denote the sum
of the squares of the dice rolls. For example, if the outcome of the roll is (1,3,4), then X=8,Y=1+9+16=26.
Find E(X) and E(Y).

Comment: I'm looking for a logical and short way to find out the expected values of given random variables

Comment: What do you know about the expectation of a sum of independent random variables?

Comment: What do you know about the expectation of a sum of random variables (independent or not)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $R_1, R_2, R_3$ denote the result of the first, second, and third roll, respectively. Then $X=\sum_{i=1}^3 R_i$ and $Y=\sum_{i=1}^3 R_i^2$. Then by linearity of expectation, $\mathbb{E}(X)=\sum_{i=1}^3 \mathbb{E}(R_1)$ and $\mathbb{E}(Y)=\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}(R_i^2)$.

Also note that $R_1, R_2, R_3$ have the same distribution, and therefore have the same expectations. Therefore we can find $\mathbb{E}(R_1)$ and $\mathbb{E}(R_1^2)$ and triple them to get the expectations of $X$ and $Y$.

Let $R$ denote the outcome of a single roll. Then $$\mathbb{E}(R)=\sum_{i=1}^6 i \mathbb{P}(R=i)=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{i=1}^6 i$$ and $$\mathbb{E}(R^2)=\sum_{i=1}^6 i^2 \mathbb{P}(R^2=i^2)=\sum_{i=1}^6 i^2\mathbb{P}(R=i)=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{i=1}^6 i^2.$$